# Pipe ffmpeg to oggenc(2) with .NET

Tags: .net, ffmpeg, stdout, stdin, pipe

I am trying to encode ogg files at -q 6/192k. ffmpeg doesnt seem to be listenting to my command

```
ffmpeg -i blah -acodec vorbis -ab 192k -y out.ogg
```

So i would like to use the [recommended ogg encoder](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Recommended_Ogg_Vorbis#Windows_binaries). It says the input must be wav or similar. I would like to pipe a wav from ffmpeg to ogg. However not only am i unsure if oggenc2 will accept input from stdin, i have no idea how to pipe one process to another inside of .net using the Process class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, AFAIK

> Oggenc2
>
> Command line encoder - allows direct
>   input of '.flac', '.ape', '.wv',
>   '.pac', '.ofr' and '.shn' files -
>   ICL7.1 compile

Suppose you don't need

> to pipe one process to another inside
>   of .net using the Process class

because there is a more easier way to do this. Try the following construction:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -f flac - | oggenc2.exe - -o audio.ogg
```

This command converts an input `mp3` file (I didn't find other audio files on my PC) to `flac` and sends it to `stdout`, which goes to `stdin` of `oggenc2` by using pipe(`|`).

The only thing you have to do is to write a .`NET` wrapper to run `ffmpeg`.

Comment: I use Process in system.diagnostics. Why do i need a wrapper? I'll write another question about piping and i think i'll use the command above. i'll be back soon (after an answer to that question) to accept i think this will work!

Comment: Under the "wrapper" I meant System.Diagnostics.Process class :)